# Select records but if null, show a message

Tags: t-sql

I know this easy, just can't get the syntax right.  If no results, show a message instead:

```
select COALESCE(select SomeField from SomeTable where [@SomeTableVariable].SomeID = @SomeID, 'none to delete')
```

Comment: Are you wanting the message to display when "if SomeField is null" for each record returned, or "if query returns 0 records"?

Comment: if the query returns 0 records...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if that query is only going to return one row then:

```
select COALESCE( 
  (select SomeField from SomeTable where [@SomeTableVariable].SomeID = @SomeID),
  'none to delete'
)
```

should do it.